Getting error in lambda function trying to assume role
I have a stack with one IAM role that is to be assumed inside the lambda runtime, and a Lambda function for which I've added permission to execute sts:AssumeRole (using AWS SDK).
The problem is that Im getting an AccessDenied  error when I execute the Lambda function.
This is the Lambda infrastructure:
const roleAssumedInLambdaRunTime = new Role(this, "GrantS3AccessRole", {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
      inlinePolicies: {
        S3FullAccess: new PolicyDocument({
          statements: [
            new PolicyStatement({
              effect: Effect.ALLOW,
              actions: ["s3:*"],
              resources: ["*"],
            }),
          ],
        }),
      },
    });

    const lambdaFn = new NodejsFunction(this, "TestSTSLambda11", {
      memorySize: 1024,
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      handler: "handler",
      entry: path.join(__dirname, `../../handlers/lambda-assume-sts-role.ts`),
      environment: {
        ASSUME_ROLE_ARN: roleAssumedInLambdaRunTime.roleArn,
      },
    });
    lambdaFn.addToRolePolicy(
      new PolicyStatement({
        sid: "AllowSTSAssumeRole",
        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: ["sts:AssumeRole"],
        resources: ["*"],
      })
    );
    lambdaFn.node.addDependency(roleAssumedInLambdaRunTime);

The Lambda function:
import { AssumeRoleCommand, STSClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-sts";

export async function handler() {
  const stsClient = new STSClient({ region: "eu-central-1" });
  const assumeRoleArn = process.env.ASSUME_ROLE_ARN;
  console.log(` assumeRoleArn = `, assumeRoleArn);

  const result = await stsClient.send(
    new AssumeRoleCommand({
      RoleArn: assumeRoleArn,
      RoleSessionName: "mySession",
      DurationSeconds: 3600, // 1 hour
    })
  );

  console.log(`result  = `, result);
  return {
    status: "OKAY",
  };
}

When I test the lambda execution I get the following error:

"errorType": "AccessDenied",
"errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::111111111111:assumed-role/TestLambdaWithSts-TestSTSLambda11ServiceRole3AAAA89-x420WaTiw1LF/TestLambdaWithSts-TestSTSLambda11D1433AEF-gRhoA42zLw1k is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/TestLambdaWithSts-GrantS3AccessRole1D33947E-OFL9jGuPP02I",


Your role's trust policy only allows it to be assumed by the lambda service principal, not by any IAM role.

Take a look at the trust relationship defined for the TestLambdaWithSts-TestSTSLambdaServiceRoleASDASD role.  A role itself must define who is allowed to assume it.  It needs a trust relationship policy that grants access for TestLambdaxyz to assume it since it appears from the error message that your lambda is configured to run using the TestLambdaxyz.
This article goes into details on how to set up the permissions required to allow this sort of role chaining.  Also see
How to assume an AWS role from another AWS role?

Thanks for your comment @Shawn
I changed the original post: Added a new role GrantS3AccessRole with principal lambda-amazonaws.com so that it can be assumed by lambda. Unfortunatelly that didnt solve the problem

The principal you need to add is not lambda-amazonaws.com, but some other role.  The error says assumed-role/TestLambdaWithSts-TestSTSLambda11ServiceRole3AAAA89-x420WaTiw1LF/TestLambdaWithSts-TestSTSLambda11D1433AEF-gRhoA42zLw1k is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/TestLambdaWithSts-GrantS3AccessRole1D33947E-OFL9jGuPP02I.  It is essentially saying role A is not allowed to assume role B.  So you must modify role B and add role A to its trust relationship.
